# A question on the limit at infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I appreciate anyone if help me to solve the following problem:

$\sqrt[\pi]{4}=Lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\,\, \frac{\pi}{2\, tg^{-1}(n)}\, \frac{\pi}{2\, tg^{-1}(n+1)}\cdots \, \frac{\pi}{2\, tg^{-1}(2n)}$

Comment: What is $tg^{-1}$?

Comment: It is the inverse function of the tangent, i.e., Arctan(n).